# How do we create a MvxRecyclerView as a child inside a Parent MvxRecyclerView using MVVMCross Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my project , i want to create a MvxRecyclerView to show all the products which user purchased on particular dates.So i have a main MvxRecyclerView layout and a Adapter class which extends MvxRecyclerAdapter .Inside this MvxRecyclerAdapter , iam creating a layouts which contains MvxRecyclerView  which populates all the items based on date.

When i tried to create the adapter, Mvvmcross is not showing the child adapter data since OnCreateViewHolder of the child adapter is throwing error.

Please check My parent Adapter class below:

```
   public class MyRecyler1Adapter: MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
    private Activity _activity;
    public static int MEETING_TYPE = 0;
    public static int DOCUMENTS_TYPE = 1;
    public NewResponse _response;

    Meeting1Adapter adapter;
    Documents1Adapter docadapter;


    public List<MeetingDetails> meetingDetailList { get; set; }


    public List<DocumentDetails> docDetailsList { get; set; }
    public bool btnDocStatus = false;
    public NewViewModel viewModel;

    public MyRecyler1Adapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, Activity context, NewResponse response,NewViewModel model) 
        : base(bindingContext)
    {
        this._activity = context;
        this._response = response;
        this.viewModel = model;

    }


    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }



    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        if (position == 0 && _response.Meetings != null)
        {
            var meeting = holder as MeetingsTypeViewHolder;
            meeting.txtMeg.Text = "Meeting";_response.Meetings.Meetings[position].MeetingTitle+position);

            adapter = new Meeting1Adapter(BindingContext, _activity, _response.Meetings);
            meeting.recycle.SetAdapter(adapter);
            meetingDetailList = _response.Meetings.Meetings;
        }
        else if (position == 1 && _response.Documents != null)
        {
            var documents = holder as DocumentsTypeViewHolder;
            documents.txtMsg.Text = "Documents";

            docadapter = new Documents1Adapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext,_activity, _response.Documents);
            documents.recycle.SetAdapter(docadapter);
            docDetailsList = _response.Documents.Documents;



        }

 public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView;
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case 0:
                if (_response.Meetings != null)
                {
                    var itemBindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, this.BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);

                    var id = Resource.Layout.layout1;
                    itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(id, parent, false);
                    return new MeetingsTypeViewHolder(itemView, itemBindingContext);
                }

            case 1:
                if (_response.Documents != null)
                {
                    var itemBindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, this.BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);

                    var id1 = Resource.Layout.layout2;
                    itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(id1, parent, false);
                    return new DocumentsTypeViewHolder(itemView, itemBindingContext);
                }


        }
        return null;
    }

  public class MeetingsTypeViewHolder : MvxRecyclerViewHolder
    {
        public TextView txtMeg { get; private set; }
        public MvxRecyclerView recycle { get; set; }
        public Button btnShowMore { get; set; }

        public MeetingsTypeViewHolder(View itemView, IMvxAndroidBindingContext context) : base(itemView, context)
        {
            txtMeg = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            recycle = itemView.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.rec1);
            btnShowMore = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShowMore);
        }
    }
    public class DocumentsTypeViewHolder : MvxRecyclerViewHolder
    {
        public TextView txtMsg { get; private set; }
        public RecyclerView recycle { get; set; }
        public Button btnShowMore { get; set; }
        public DocumentsTypeViewHolder(View itemView, IMvxAndroidBindingContext context) : base(itemView, context)
        {
            txtMsg = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            recycle = itemView.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.rec1);
            btnShowMore = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShowMore);

        }
    }

  public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return MEETING_TYPE;
            case 1:
                return DOCUMENTS_TYPE;

            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }


}
```

Child adapter sample:

```
  public class Meeting1Adapter: MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    public MeetingsMain meetingMain { get; set; }
    public Meeting1Adapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, Activity activity, MeetingsMain meetingsMain)
       : base(bindingContext)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.meetingMain = meetingsMain;
    }


    public void RefreshItems(Object response)
    {
        if (response is List<ContactDetails>)
            meetingMain.Meetings = (List<MeetingDetails>)response;
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return meetingMain.Meetings.Count; }
    }



    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var meeting = holder as MeetingsAdapterValueTypeViewHolder;

        meeting.txtMeg.Text = meetingMain.Meetings[position].MeetingTitle;



    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        try
        {
            var itemBindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, this.BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);

            var id = Resource.Layout.item_layout;
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(id, parent, false);
            return new MeetingsAdapterValueTypeViewHolder(itemView, itemBindingContext);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in response ## " + e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class MeetingsAdapterValueTypeViewHolder : MvxRecyclerViewHolder
    {
        // public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView txtMeg { get; private set; }

        public MeetingsAdapterValueTypeViewHolder(View itemView, IMvxAndroidBindingContext ctxt) : base(itemView,ctxt)
        {

             txtMeg = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Problem : In the child adapter ,OnCreateViewHolder () method is not calling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days in searching the solution ,finally i got the result.

The main thing we should check while loading MvxRecyclerview is

```
1: MvxRecyclerView.LayoutManager.
2:In Child Adapter,Since we are using MvxRecyclerView,we should use IMvxAndroidBindingContext 
  and the associated adapter changes like 
   a:Adapter should extend MvxRecyclerAdapter
   b: use  MvxRecyclerViewHolder
```

**------------------------------------------Edit Your Adapter in the below mentioned way----**

Code change made in MyRecyler1Adapter:

```
MvxRecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;//Dont use RecyclerView.LayoutManager
```

Inside the OnBindViewHolder()

```
 layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(_activity, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
            meeting.recycle.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Inside Child Adapter:

```
 public class Meeting1Adapter: MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    public IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingCtxt;
    protected IMvxAndroidBindingContext BindingContext => bindingCtxt;
    public MeetingsMain meetingMain { get; set; }
    public Meeting1Adapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, Activity activity, MeetingsMain meetingsMain)
    {
        this.bindingCtxt = bindingContext;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.meetingMain = meetingsMain;
    }

 ----


   public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        try
        {
            var itemBindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, this.BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);

            var id = Resource.Layout.item_layout;
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(id, parent, false);
            return new MeetingsAdapterValueTypeViewHolder(itemView, itemBindingContext);
           // return new MeetingsAdapterValueTypeViewHolder(itemView);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in response ## " + e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }


 ----
}
```